# How am I supposed to configure Jwt Bearer authentication?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, jwt

I am trying to make an web application that uses Jwt token authentication, logging on ect works fine.
Now I'm trying to add authorisation on who can access what pages and so on. On my controller I added `[Authorize]`. But when I'm logged in and try to go to one of the actions I always get a blank page and when I inspect it the action always returns 401 Unauthorized, any suggestions?

My headerservice for sending the authorization header to the Api:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace RelationizeWeb.Facade.Services
{
    public class HeaderService : IHeaderService
    {
        private const string AuthorizationHeaderKey = "Authorization";
        private const string BearerHeaderValue = "Bearer";

        public Dictionary<string, List<string>> CreateAuthorizationHeader(string token)
        {
            var dict = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>
            {
                { AuthorizationHeaderKey, new List<string>{ $"{BearerHeaderValue} {token}" } }
            };
            return dict;
        }

        public Dictionary<string, List<string>> CreateHeader(string key, string value)
        {
            var dict = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>
            {
                { key, new List<string> { value } }
            };
            return dict;
        }
    }
}
```

Example of an Api request we make in for example our OpinionMakerService:

```
public IEnumerable<OpinionMaker> GetOpinionMakers(JwtTokenResponse jwt)
    {
        try
        {
            return (List<OpinionMaker>)_relationizeApiAgent.GetOpinionMakersWithHttpMessages(_headerService.CreateAuthorizationHeader(jwt.AccessToken)).Body;
        }
        catch(Exception)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you using .NET Core?

Comment: Yes I am using the .NET Core framework

Comment: When we started this project some weeks ago we started by just always redirecting to the login page, which is unsufficient now that we added more than just a login. We also want some public pages and figured this was the best approach

Comment: Running it without IIS I managed to catch this error `Authorization failed for user: (null).` Any suggestions?

Comment: The Claim Identity is not set for the logged in User

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use azure to generate the JWT for your application . You need to call an extension method named `UseJwtBearerAuthentication` in the `StartUp.cs` file for the REST api and use `[Authorize]` attribute to the controllers . The `UseJwtBearerAuthentication` method works like below

```
app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerOptions
            {
                AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
                AutomaticChallenge = true,
                Authority = <your auth name>,
                Audience = <target audience URL>
            });
```

Please see the links below for more reference
1.[https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/04/06/jwt-validation-and-authorization-in-asp-net-core/](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/premier_developer/2017/04/26/using-adal-with-angular2/)

2. https://pioneercode.com/post/authentication-in-an-asp-dot-net-core-api-part-3-json-web-token

you can use a client side library like ADAL.JS to call the azure service to obtain a JWT bearer token and then send the token in each request to controller. It will be verified in each request. We followed this approach in an Angular2 app with Azure JWT authentication.

Link for adal.js 
https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js

Resource :
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/premier_developer/2017/04/26/using-adal-with-angular2/

edit : you can use the below code to access JWT Token and add it to the Authorization header before making a call to controller from another controller

```
 HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    var token = <add your token here>; // call GetToken() method here and extract access_token from JwtTokenResponse class property.
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new 
    AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token.Substring("Bearer ".Length).Trim());

    //call the api method using SendAsync() or PostAsyc() etc.
```

Comment: Could you explain what those options do? And how I find out what to put in Authority and Audience? Cause I am pretty new to this...

Comment: Check the MSDN link .. every option is explained there.

Comment: Even with configuring it like that I'm still only getting 401 responses, even though I'm pretty sure I am logged in.

Comment: are you using azure and adal.js?You have to send the token from client side to verify it server side before invoking the action in controller. Check the network tab in chrome to see whether you are sending the bearer token.

Comment: No I am not, the token is already being send from controller to controller it just doesn't verify it as valid. Also I'm not able to translate angular into C#...

Comment: So far this is the code I put into my startup.cs: `app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerOptions
            {
                AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
                AutomaticChallenge = true,
                Authority = "http://localhost:5122/",
                Audience = "http://localhost:5122/",
                RequireHttpsMetadata = false,
                AuthenticationScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme
            });` But it still gives me a 401 response on the controller that has the authorize attribute

Comment: in case of controller to controller call using `httpclient` then you have to set the token in the `Authorization` request header before making the httpclient call like below 

`string token = request.Headers["Authorization"];
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token.Substring("Bearer ".Length).Trim());`

Comment: I can't seem to use Client.* and my Request.Headers is always equal to a number of null fields. Other suggestions that might point me in the good direction? My Jwt token is stored in the HttpContext, maybe that'll help?

Comment: Can you post the code where you are seeing the value of JWT token in httpcontext ? under which property?` client ` is an instance of `httpclient` here

Comment: This is the function we use to return the JwtToken: `public JwtTokenResponse GetToken()
        {
            return HttpContext.Session.Get<JwtTokenResponse>("access_token");
        }`

Comment: updated my answer for calling controller from another controller

Comment: Should I call that piece of code in the OnActionExecuting? Cause we got a headerservice that helps sending the token towards the Api. The problem is that my user is unauthorized to access the action OpinionMaker/List (controller is outfitted with an `[Authorized]` attribute)

Comment: Can you post the code for header service in your actual question where it sends the token to the api.

Comment: Sending header to the Api works fine. Just accessing a view is where it all goes wrong. Updated my question.